# Laravel 8:Property [Name] does not exist on this collection instance

Tags: laravel-8

I am using Laravel8 .Given below is code in controller for query

```
 $Applications = Applications::where('applications.Id', $id)
->select(DB::raw("applications.*,attachments.*,attachmentdetails.*"))
 ->leftjoin('attachments','applications.Id', '=', 'attachments.application_id')
->leftjoin('attachmentdetails','attachments.id', '=', 'attachmentdetails.attachmentId') 
->get();
```

This is the result:In the result I can find Name

```
#original: array:24 [▼
        "Id" => 1
        "id" => 1
        "Name" => "test"
        "Lastname" => "k"
        "Address" => "mansoura"
        "Email" => "test@abc.com"
        "Nationality" => "Austria"
        "Place_of_birth" => "qa"
        "Country_of_residence" => "Qatar"
        "DOB" => "2021-10-12"
        "Workplace" => "austria"
        "CV" => "desrts_1634628674.jpg"
        "phone_number" => 342343
        "photo" => "waterfall_1634628674.jpg"
        "ID_attachment" => "logo (2)_1634628674.png"
        "AttachmentTypeId" => 1
        "status" => 1
        "updated_at" => "2021-10-19 07:31:14"
        "created_at" => "2021-10-19 07:31:14"
        "application_id" => "1"
        "attachmentTypeId" => 1
        "attachmentId" => 1
        "applicationId" => "1"
        "attachment" => "I CAN READ HEAD (1).pdf"
      ]
```

this is the code in view page:

```
{{$Applications->Name}}
```

But in view  I am getting error:

> Property [Name] does not exist on this collection instance.

I am getting result in executing query..Pls help

Comment: Can you share the code of what you're actually running in your view?

Comment: Undefined index: Name

Comment: this is the view: just displaying contents in a table <table><tr><td>Name</td>
      <td>{{$Applications->Name}}</td>
      </tr>
      <tr><td>Last Name</td>
      <td>{{ $Applications->Lastname }}</td>
      </tr>
      <tr><td> Address</td>
      <td>>{{ $Applications->Address }} </td>
      </tr>
       <tr><td>Email</td>
      <td>{{ $Applications->Email }}</td>
      </tr>
       <tr><td>Nationality</td>
      <td>{{ $Applications->Nationality }}</td>
      </tr>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use the query builder's `get` method, you receive a `Collection` of results.

If your comment with the table in your view is to be taken literally, you are trying to access the `Collection` of results as if it was a single record.

If you iterate over the `$Applications`, you will get access to each one and then your properties will exist. One way to do this in Blade is with an `@foreach` loop; I'll let you look up how to use this.

Alternatively, if you only want to retrieve one application and not have a `Collection` then you can use `first()` instead of `get()` and you'll get the first matching record.